# Bring main application form in front

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i am working on compact framework 3.5, with this issue.`ScanOutMenu` is a form with two buttons and only in this screen `BringToFront()` is not working.In all other screen i have input field where it got focus and `BringToFront()` take the form in front.

```
private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    ScanOutMenu scanOutMenu = new ScanOutMenu();
    scanOutMenu.BringToFront();
}
```

Also I tried `scanOutMenu.TopMost = true;` which is also not working.I think since `ScanOutMenu` form don't have input field and no focus `BringToFront()` is not working.

`ScanOutMenu` form is the main application form and i need to bring the screen in front without using `scanOutMenu.Show()` or `scanOutMenu.ShowDialog()`

Comment: Form is already open and behind the FileExplore.I need to take that to front.But if i use BringToFront(),i can see the menu of my form and body of form is merged with FileExplorer folders.

Comment: In the code You posted, You are creating a **new** instance of `ScanOutMenu` form and bringing this one to front, which seems not a desirable behavior. If the form is already opened, You should have a reference to the opened instance of the form accessible from `menuItem1_Click` and call `BringToFront()` on that instance. The code You posted is part of another form, is this correct? If so, maybe You can assign the `Owner` property when creating the other form and then read the form instance from it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Enabling the TopMost Property?

```
this.TopMost = true;

//then if you want to remove it just put to false
```

Comment: I tried scanOutMenu.TopMost = true; also not working

Comment: if you want to open it you MUST use show() or showDialog() (unless it is already open and you need to bring to front)

Comment: Form is already open and behind the FileExplore.I need to take that to front.But if i use BringToFront(),i can see the menu of my form and body of form is merged with FileExplorer folders.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later, when working on a CE app, you have to get your hands dirty with Windows API calls.  `SetForegroundWindow` may do what you're after

```
// Import the API call
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

// Then, in your code somewhere
SetForegroundWindow(scanOutMenu.Handle);
```

See API docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940024.aspx

Comment: Form is already open and behind the FileExplore.I need to take that to front.But if i use BringToFront(),i can see the menu of my form and body of form is merged with FileExplorer folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it open then you need to bring to front the Object that is open.
In the example you show you are bringing to front a object that has not been shown yet.

```
ScanOutMenu scanOutMenu = new ScanOutMenu(); // Creates a new object
scanOutMenu.BringToFront(); //Brings to front the Object that is not shown.
```

So to open it you have to make a non-local variable with the Form you want and assign that variable the Form you want to open.

Example:

```
class test{

AnotherForm op;

public test(){
  AnotherForm nForm = new AnotherForm(); //Starts a form object
  op = nForm; // Assigns the form to be shown to the non-local variable
  nForm.Show(); // shows the form object to user

}

private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  op.BringToFront(); //This will work
}

}
```